# Overflow-x is visible on iphone whatever i do

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

Trying to block the overflow-x for smartphones with following css

```
html, body {
width: 100% !important; 
max-width:100% !important; 
overflow-x:hidden !important;
}
```

I've also got absolute div with following styles

```
.cartslidewrap {
position:absolute;
width:320px;
right:-380px;
}
```

Android seems to be working fine with it, but iphone still sees that overflow and shows hidden div when screen is swiped.

Comment: Can you please provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (or put your code online elsewhere) so we could test it? It's really hard to tell what's going wrong without being able to see your code and run it on our own device(s).